# How to add parametres to a Google Data studio complex query in postgres connector

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a postgres database that contains some data accumulated over time and I want to build reports that only show a controllable date range (like on the report page the user can specify the dates that he want the data from) without returning and changing the query itself (like select * from table where date between: start and: end) those start and end parameters can be defined from the outside of the query